# Javascript: open link and add css styles

Tags: javascript, css

I need to open link in new tab and add css style to div on the new page. There is my code

```
$('#add_member').click(function() {
  url = "example.com";

  details = window.open(url);
  details.document.getElementsByClassName("invite-team-popup").style.display = "block !important";
});
```

Link opening perfectly but styling not working. What did I miss? Thanks!

Comment: Do you control the other page (same domain)?

Comment: @NathanTaylor of course, link in the code is just an example

Comment: Note that you can't add `!important` styles with javascript, and that `getElements...` gets a collectio

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("invite-team-popup")
```

gives you an array-like item (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodelist.asp) not a list of nodes like in jQuery, so you can not change styles for all of them directly. Use jquery

```
$('.invite-team-popup')
```

or iterate

Comment: but I need to change styles on the new tab, are you sure that your solution works?

Comment: if you want use native JS solution, then you need to iterate: var items = details.document.getElementsByClassName("invite-team-popup"); for (var i=0; i<items.length;i++) {items[i].style.display = 'block'}